# How to use object keys in an interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have an interface for a redux action which uses **action_types** stored in an object. But it doesn't allow me to do.

```
const action_types = {
  USER_SUCCESS: 'USER_SUCCESS',
  USER_REQUEST: 'USER_REQUEST'    
}

interface IUpdateUser {
  type: action_types.USER_SUCCESS,    // Returns error
  payload:{
    value: string
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn `action_types` into an enum:

```
enum action_types {
  USER_SUCCESS = 'USER_SUCCESS',
  USER_REQUEST = 'USER_REQUEST' 
}

interface IUpdateUser {
  type: action_types.USER_SUCCESS,
  payload:{
    value: string
  }
}
```

This way you'll get exhaustiveness checking when you use a `switch` on the action type as well.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong for accessing the type of a property. You need to use `[]`to access property types and `typeof` to get the type of the const.

```
const action_types = {
  USER_SUCCESS: 'USER_SUCCESS' as 'USER_SUCCESS',
  USER_REQUEST: 'USER_REQUEST' as 'USER_REQUEST'    
}

interface IUpdateUser {
  type: typeof action_types['USER_SUCCESS'],    // ok
  payload:{
    value: string
  }
}


interface IUpdateUser {
  type: typeof action_types['USER_SUCCESS'],    // ok
  payload:{
    value: string
  }
}
```